# How to extract number out of an alphanumeric text?

Tags: vba, excel

my string in excel could be anything like 213221-sddc  or 232323/scdscsd   or any separator between the number and characters...  How can i extract only numbers out of this text ?

Comment: since my hands are quite itchy I wrote a code with reference to the function I mentioned from the comments. So there's no cross posting. But to give you an insight how you want to read your Excel Cell Range to process text and then output. Hope gets you going ;)

Comment: no need for so much code when you can use Regex

Comment: if your numbers are always at the front of the string then a regexp is overkill.

Answer (score 7):

use Regex. I have cast strNoAlpha as a Double but this can also be a string if required.

```
Dim str As String, strNoAlpha As Double

str = "213221-sddc"
With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = "[^\d]+"
    .Global = True
    strNoAlpha = Trim(.Replace(str, vbNullString))
End With
```

Or as a UDF:

```
Function removeAlpha(rng As Range) As Double

    If (rng.Count <> 1) Then
        removeAlpha = "Only select one cell"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim str As String

    str = rng.Value2

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "[^\d]+"
        .Global = True
        removeAlpha = Trim(.Replace(str, vbNullString))
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: + 1 For RegEx. You might also want to use `Trim(strNoAlpha)` to remove the spaces?

Comment: spaces are removed by \d which only returns digits but generally its a good technique.

Comment: `strNoAlpha = .Replace(str, vbNullString)` doesn't remove spaces... Try this `Debug.Print Len(Trim(strNoAlpha))` and `Debug.Print Len(strNoAlpha)` The first one will give you 6 and the second one will give you 8....

Comment: yes but the Pattern does .Pattern = "[^\d]+" which removes anything but digits.

Comment: for the input str = " 213221-sddc " it returns 6 for both.

Comment: couple of points, I return a double so not possible to have a leading or trailing space but also even when I type this as a String it will count the space as a non digit and the regex will remove it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21088/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-philip-a-barnes)

Comment: added Trim, Regex is inconsistent in how it deals with this. Removing all non digits actually keeps spaces! Thanks Siddharth for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is just a start where you may read all your alphanumeric text from a range (as per the image) then using the [**ABOVE MENTIONED FUNCTION** From Dave and Richie](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=18185)

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestRange()
Dim numberArray As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim strTemp As String

    numberArray = Application.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("B4:B11"))

    For i = LBound(numberArray) To UBound(numberArray)
        strTemp = numberArray(i)
        numberArray(i) = ExtractNumber(strTemp) '-- **You use above mentioned function**
    Next i

'Output the processed array into the Sheet.
Sheets(1).Range("C4").Resize(UBound(numberArray), _
LBound(numberArray)) = Application.Transpose(numberArray)

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Testing:**

```
Public Sub AlphaNumericTest()

 Dim AlphaNumericStr As String
 AlphaNumericStr = "A100"

 Dim SeqStartNum As Double, SeqStartAlpha As String
 SeqStartNum = NumericBreakdown(AlphaNumericStr)
 SeqStartAlpha = AlphaBreakdown(AlphaNumericStr)
 Debug.Print "Seq Alpha = " & SeqStartAlpha
 Debug.Print "Seq Num = " & SeqStartNum

End Sub
```

**Function for Alpha Portion:**

```
Public Function AlphaBreakdown(str As String) As String
 With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  .Pattern = "[^\D]+"
  .Global = True
  AlphaBreakdown = Trim(.Replace(str, vbNullString))
  Debug.Print "Alpha = " & AlphaBreakdown
 End With
End Function
```

**Function for Numeric Portion:**

```
Public Function NumericBreakdown(str As String) As Double
 With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  .Pattern = "[^\d]+"
  .Global = True
  NumericBreakdown = Trim(.Replace(str, vbNullString))
  Debug.Print "Numeric = " & NumericBreakdown
 End With
End Function
```