# Split numbers from column into another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have this data in column

[image]

now i want to extract last numbers and put into another column ..

how i do this

Comment: There seem to be a space, so text to columns will do this just fine (unless you not showing all different possible combinations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract just numbers from a string

```
=MID(A1,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")),99)*1
```

Comment: It is extracting numbers when digits are at last of string. What will happen when numbers are middle of string? Like `Harun24HR`. How i will separate `24` from `Harun24HR`?

Comment: @Harun24HR- this is not what the OP asked. But check out this thread.[How to extract number out of an alphanumeric text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859560/how-to-extract-number-out-of-an-alphanumeric-text)

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the column with the data
2. Data tab - Data Tools - Text to Columns
3. Tick Delimited - Next
4. Tick Space - Next
5. Finish

**Results:**

[image]